# ion-select select default value not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have ion-select with that have many options and I have when the view is ready to select one default value depending on CurrentNumber. i have this code:

```
<ion-select formControlName="Level">
          <ion-option [value]="level.id" *ngFor="let level of levels" [attr.selected]="(level.levelNumber == currentLevel)? true : null">
             {{level.name}}
          </ion-option>
</ion-select>

this.currentLevel = 1;
```

the data comes from the server like that :

```
data = [
 {
  levelNumber : 1,
  name:'abcd'
 },
 {
levelNumber:2,
name:'efg'
 }
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of the `selected` attribute, you can set the default option in the control when the data is ready:

```
// When the data is ready
this.yourForm.get('Level').setValue(data.id);
```

That will set the option with id equal to `data.id` as the default.

Answer (score 6):

I find a way with the placeholder

```html
<ion-select id="genderInput" [formControl]="gender" [placeholder]="gender.value.toUpperCase() | translate">
   <ion-option value="female">{{ 'FEMALE' | translate }}</ion-option>
   <ion-option value="male">{{ 'MALE' | translate }}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

also have to add the following styles to override the default color of a placeholder

```scss
ion-select {
   div.select-text.select-placeholder {
      color: get-color(black) !important;
   }
}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, i'd spent ages trying to work around this. The placeholder is the way to go. Worked perfectly

Comment: sounds like an ugly hack but to be honnest it is the cleannest way i found to make it works within ionic3 + FormControl. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Then there is this: Example straight from [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/select/select.ts)

```
 * ### Object Value References
 *
 * When using objects for select values, it is possible for the identities of these objects to
 * change if they are coming from a server or database, while the selected value's identity
 * remains the same. For example, this can occur when an existing record with the desired object value
 * is loaded into the select, but the newly retrieved select options now have different identities. This will
 * result in the select appearing to have no value at all, even though the original selection in still intact.
 *
 * Using the `compareWith` `Input` is the solution to this problem
 *
```

```html
 <ion-item>
   <ion-label>Employee</ion-label>
   <ion-select [(ngModel)]="employee" [compareWith]="compareFn">
     <ion-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" [value]="employee">{{employee.name}}</ion-option>
   </ion-select>
 </ion-item>
```

```javascript
 compareFn(e1: Employee, e2: Employee): boolean {
   return e1 && e2 ? e1.id === e2.id : e1 === e2;
 }
```

Comment: many many thanks! This is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

When your options are not dynamic and static, you can do this -

In your typescript: -

```
this.myForm= this.formBuilder.group({
      selectOptionName: ['ValueHere', Validators.required]
    });
```

In your HTML :-

```
<ion-select formControlName = 'selectOptionName' value="ValueHere">
    <ion-select-option value="ValueHere">Value-1</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="ValueHere2">Value-2</ion-select-option>
 </ion-select>
```

Comment: Thanx for the appreciation

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

HTML -

```
<ion-select formControlName="Level">
      <ion-option [value]="level.id" *ngFor="let level of levels" >
         {{level.name}}
      </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

TS -

```
__formGroupInstance  : FormGroup

this.__formGroupInstance  = this.formBuilder.group({
Level: this.currentLevel 
})
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do it like below:

```html
<ion-select formControlName="Level">
  <ion-option *ngFor="let level of levels" value="{{level.id}}" [selected]="level.levelNumber == currentLevel">
    {{level.name}}
  </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```